# How can I add my own event listener to my custom React Native component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

So I'm using React Native+Expo and I made a custom component that's a stepper.
Looks like this:
[image]

This is the code for it:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text,StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';



const Stepper = (props) => {
    let counter = 0;

    const increment = () => {
        counter += 1

    }
    
    const decrement = () => {
        counter -= 1
    }

    return (

        <View style={{ ...styles.stepperStyle, ...props.containerStyle }}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{
                backgroundColor: props.leftColor,
                flex: 1,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                borderTopLeftRadius: props.radius,
                borderBottomLeftRadius: props.radius
            }}>
                <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit={true} style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>-</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={{
                borderLeftWidth: 1,
                borderRightWidth: 1,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                flex: 1
            }}>
                <Text style={props.labelStyle}>{props.initialValue} {props.label}</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{
                backgroundColor: props.rightColor,
                flex: 1,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                borderTopRightRadius: props.radius,
                borderBottomRightRadius: props.radius
            }}>
                <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}
                    style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>+</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

    );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    stepperStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderRadius: 100,
        borderWidth: 1,
        width: '100%',
        height: 42
    }

});
export default Stepper
```

What I want to do is make some sort of event listener or function that can return the counter value whenever it has changed.

So from the outside, I'd want it to look like this:

```
<Stepper
   onValueChange={count => setSets(count)}
/>
```

I'm new to doing something like this. Would I need to use the useEffect hook? What would be the best way to just get the current counter value? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like you want the value inside the component to match the stateful `sets` value outside the component, the most reasonable way to handle this would be to pass both the `sets` and `setSets` down as props, and use and call those through `increment` and `decrement`.

```
<Stepper
   {...{ sets, setSets }}
/>
```

```
const Stepper = ({ sets, setSets }) => {
    const increment = () => setSets(sets + 1);
    const decrement = () => setSets(sets - 1);
    // other code that references increment and decrement and sets
```

If the outer state name can change, use

```
<Stepper
    counter={sets} setCounter={setSets}
/>
```

```
const Stepper = ({ counter, setCounter }) => {
    const increment = () => setCounter(counter + 1);
    const decrement = () => setCounter(counter - 1);
    // other code that references increment and decrement and counter
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So if I have two Steppers. One for sets and for reps(Both are stateful). How would that work? Can I rename the props you made above to something else?